# Splitting one column into three using a delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

Back with another problem. I recently grabbed some confidence interval across employees attendance rate at my business and converted the results into a dframe:

```
def mean_confidence_interval(unstacked, confidence=0.9):
    a = 1.0 * np.array(unstacked)
    n = len(a)
    m, se = np.nanmean(a), scipy.stats.sem(a, nan_policy='omit')
    h = se * scipy.stats.t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2., n-1)
    return m, m-h, m+h

answer = unstacked.apply(mean_confidence_interval)
answer = answer.to_frame(name='Interval')
answer = answer.reset_index()
answer
```

that output something similar to this

```
Employee|             Interval
-------------------------------
Karl    |      (0.75,0.70,0.80)
```

I have been trying to use the comma as a delimiter to create three new columns.

```
Mean | Low | High
```

So far I tried:

```
answer[['Mean','Low', 'High']] = answer['Interval'].str.split(',',expand=True)
answer
```

only to have it return with:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I've also tried using `str.extract` like the following:

```
p = r'(?P<Mean>-?\d+\.\d+).*?(?P<Low>-?\d+\.\d+).*?(?P<High>-?\d+\.\d+)'
answer[['Mean','Low', 'High']] = answer['Interval'].str.extract(p,expand=True)
answer
```

which returns the columns I want, but doesn't actually extract the info I want:

```
    Employee    Interval        Mean  Low  High
0   Karl    (0.75, 0.70, 0.80)  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you have a column of tuples `(0.75,0.70,0.80)` and not a column of the string `'(0.75,0.70,0.80)'`. Perhaps try `answer[['Mean','Low', 'High']] = answer.Interval.apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad it worked! But use @Wen's solution, the Series.apply isn't efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This is `tuple` not string

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Interval.values.tolist())
Out[1098]: 
      0    1    2
0  0.75  0.7  0.8

#df[['Mean','Low', 'High']]=pd.DataFrame(df.Interval.values.tolist())
```

After we change the data type to `str` , you regex will work

```
df['Interval'].astype(str).str.extract(p,expand=True)
Out[1103]: 
   Mean  Low High
0  0.75  0.7  0.8
```